# Odd bug with UISplitView - Viewport scales to iPhone size?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm working with Objective-C for the first time, and have an odd bug in an application that was given to me. The following pictures demonstrate the problem I'm having:

[image: Normal display of rotated screen]

This screen displays when the user rotates the iPad. This is normal. The control at the top (<) allows the user to hide the subview on the left side. Upon hiding the subview, the dark blue portion should expand to fill the screen. Prior to my working with the application, this worked. Now, this is happening:

[image: Bug upon hiding splitview]

I haven't found anything to explain why, exactly, this is happening. Any ideas?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addGestureRecognizers];


    // initialize the "<" button...

    toggleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[PanoUtils leftIndicator] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleScreen)];
    // the annotate button...

    annotateButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pencil.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(annotateTapped)];
    // the done button for annotations...

    doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneAnnotateTapped)];
    // a flexible spacer...

    nameFieldSpacerButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    // the accelerometer button...

    alignButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gyro.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(align:)];
    // and the search button.

    searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(searchButtonTouched:)];


    // customize the align button after the user selects it.

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gyroSelected.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(align:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    alignSelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];



    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [toolBar.items mutableCopy];

    [itemsArray addObject:searchButton];

    [itemsArray addObject:annotateButton];

    [itemsArray addObject:alignButton];

    [toolBar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];

    [itemsArray release];



    [self adjustToggleButton];



}
```

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing your code, but it seems to me that it is related to autorotate code snippet for the navitation bar. Post the view did load part that is related to placement of your navigation bar so I can offer some help. Also there is a possibility that in IB that navigation was added as an outlet and is not properly auto sized for autorotation.

Comment: Thanks! I added some code snippets of viewdidload if you get the chance to check it out.

Comment: The code seems fine. It deals with gestures and other stuff. Check the IB for autosizing. That is where the issue maybe.

Comment: Hm. I've gone through the various XIB files throughout the application and played around with the autosizing. However, I still have the same problem. Any other ideas? Thanks so much for your help, btw.

Comment: At this point I don't have any more ideas unless I actually look at your project which obliges me to provide you with my email which is not allowed on this forum. Hope that you can get some help otherwise here my email. Adrianp31@me.com